# Marriage and porn

Tags: five-precepts, sexuality, tipitaka, sexual-misconduct

We all know the limits of a married person.We all know the definition of cheating in Buddhism.

But Buddhism existed in a time Porn did not exist.

So if a married person watch porn is it cheating?

Comment: The beginnings of Buddhism are not too long before the writing of Kama Sutra. I don't think your assumption that porn didn't exist at that time is true.

Comment: Porn is a sort of modern entertainment available to the public.public. Kamasutra is not a book of porn (Like a an Adult comic book).It is an informative guide to a satisfying marriage / sex life.It was developed in a time when sex was more of an art or a form of entertainment for the nobles and royalty.I was Knowledge passed from generations combined.  I think you may have heard once sex was divine form of worship in india. @michau

Comment: I know that it isn't a book of porn, but it that shows that these topics weren't uncommon in the literature of the time. If sex manuals existed, then this topic wasn't taboo, so it's hard for me to imagine that porn in one form or another did not exist.

Comment: Maybe, But what we call porn is something to read or watch.These kind of erotic things were only available to the highest peaks of society,After going to these brothel like places they would watch them dance and sing.In the meantime they would choose who they will hire for services.So it was more like prostitution than being close to porn,These women did provided more than sex (Escorting,Real dance shows,Musicals). Thanks for the interesting conversation, I would like to discuss more.

Comment: According to buddhism, what are the limits of a married person, and the definition of cheating? Does anyone know the source?

Answer (score 9):

Technically, watching porn doesn't break the 3rd precept, but it weakens it. In other words, it weakens the merits you gain by keeping to the precept apart from  accumulating bad karma.

Comment: Does it depend on whether one is married or not?

Comment: Even if you are not married, watching porn is bad Karma for you.

Comment: But it is not a Sin it is an "Akusala" (A bad karma that would reverse your path or blunt your meditation or give you a bad birth).

Comment: The concept of sin or bad karma is an interesting one since are you not performing an act because you are scared (and if the given circumstance were ripe, you would perform them) or is it because you truly understand it. Having watched a talk on Ted - `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRJ_QfP2mhU`, you'll find that porn is based on concepts of submission, force, oppression, etc.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille is it a bad karma or something that weakens your path to nirvana? can we say > it weakens the merits you gain by keeping to the precept?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake yes, it weakens the 3rd precept and hinders the path to Nibbana.

Answer (score 7):

Some socially 'Islamic' people (as distinct from Muslim practitioners) get married on a Friday and divorce on the Monday just so they can have sex on the weekend & not break the rules. Obviously, this does not conform with the true spirit of the religion.

Similarly, regardless of whether a person is married, delighting in pornography is an expression (for men) of the mind's view ('ditthi') about women, human relationships &/or sex.

The scriptures state a wise man looks upon every woman like a [mother, sister or daughter](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.127.than.html). For example, in a traditional marriage, a wife has the primary role of a mother (rather than a sex partner).

A pornographic lifestyle & outlook is the opposite of compassion & the development of spiritually strengthening & liberating qualities.

Answer (score 3):

Donating porn/nude arts, women to men for evil purposes, bulls for cows to breed, alcohol and arranging dances(probably sexually arousing) are considered evil charity which are sinful. So clearly porn is not something good but sinful whether or not it falls under physically cheating.

Answer (score 1):

Porn conflicts with Buddhism on several levels. One of the most basic defilements in buddhism (unwholesome roots) is greed. This is a self centered desire for pleasure or possession it also stimulates another unwholesome root in Delusion. Also if we are mindful of the topic of porn, we see the the porn industry exploits people for money and has been known to be involved in drugs and sex trafficking...

When you watch porn in marriage you are deceiving your partner for self gratification..

Porn contradicts the path..